# My Function is only looping once before it breaks out. How can i fix this? Vuejs

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js

I am trying to check all items in the cart, and if the item is in the cart disable the sell button (i already have that set up for other things.) I think my loop is only looping once before exiting. how can i fix this? thanks!

The refreshCart(); Is an axios call to get latest cart and item data.

```
checkInCart: function(){
        this.refreshCart();
        if (this.currentCart.items.length > 0 ){
          for(var i=0; this.currentCart.items.length > i; i++){
            if(this.currentCart.items[i].id == this.varSelectID){
                this.refreshCart();
                this.notInCart = false;
                this.checkDisableQty();
                this.checkDisable();
            }
            else{
              this.notInCart = true;
            }
          }
        }else{
          this.notInCart = true;
        }
```

Comment: *"how can i fix this?"* Start debugging by logging the relevant values, like the `.length` you're comparing to `i`.

Comment: ...also, learning to use the debugger to to step through code as it executes is extremely valuable. The time you take to learn it will pay for itself quickly.

Comment: check this.currentCart.items[i].id and this.varSelectID by console.log

Answer (score 0):

Here `this.currentCart.items.length > i`:

```
  for(var i=0; this.currentCart.items.length > i; i++){
```

It looks like this is incorrect. Try doing `this.currentCart.items.length <= i` since this is the expression that gets evaluated if the for loop should run again.

You want to keep running the loop while i is less than the length of the array, not while i is greater than the length of the array (since i starts at 0 it can never be greater than the length of the array and so your loop never runs).